# how to download file with python selenium on github action

Tags: python, github, selenium-webdriver, github-actions

I been trying to setup a workflow on downloading file by using selenium, its works fine on my desktop, code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import sys
import re

sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

sys.path.append('./code/global_code/')
import global_function as af

chromedriver = './data/#global_rf/selenium/chromedriver.exe'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
out_path = './data/asia/japan/raw/month/'
prefs = {'download.default_directory': out_path}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)


file_name = af.search_file(out_path)

name = re.compile(r'month/(?P<name>.*?)_', re.S) 
date = [name.findall(f)[0] for f in file_name]
date = max(date)
date = '%s年%s月' % (date[:4], int(date[-2:]))
print(date)


wd = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=options)  
wd.get('https://occtonet3.occto.or.jp/public/dfw/RP11/OCCTO/SD/LOGIN_login#')  

handles = wd.window_handles
wd.switch_to.window(handles[1])
wd.close()  
wd.switch_to.window(handles[0])  
wd.implicitly_wait(60)
wd.find_element(By.ID, 'menu1-6').click()
wd.find_element(By.ID, 'menu1-6-3-1').click()
handles = wd.window_handles
wd.switch_to.window(handles[1])  

select = Select(wd.find_element(By.ID, 'ktgr'))
select.select_by_value('7')  
wd.find_element(By.ID, 'searchBtn').click()


test = wd.find_element(By.ID, 'table3_rows_0__infNm')
if date in test.text:
    print('not update yet')
else:
    wd.find_element(By.ID, 'table3_rows_0__pdfCsvBtn').click()
    time.sleep(10)
    confirm_text = 'ui-button-text'
    wd.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, confirm_text)[2].click()
    print('downloading...')
    time.sleep(30)
# wd.quit()
```

everything works fine, I can download what I want to where I want it.
However, when I was tring to setup a workflow on github, it could run, but didnt download anything, the code is below:

```
name: test
'on':
  schedule:
    - cron: 0 22 * * *
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: check_code
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-Python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'
      - name: install requirements
        run: |
          pip install selenium
      - name: process data
        run: |
          python ./code/asian/japan/japan_selenium.py
      - name: commit and push if it changed
        run: |
          git config user.name "${GITHUB_ACTOR}"
          git config user.email "${GITHUB_ACTOR}@users.noreply.github.com"
          git add -A
          git commit -m 'updated'
          git push
```

After hours of debug, I think the prpblem is I cant set the default download path in github action, anyone have any good thoughts about what I went wrong?

```
out_path = './data/asia/japan/raw/month/'
prefs = {'download.default_directory': out_path}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update: I can safely to say that the problem is the chrome default download path:(

Comment: Please note, the presented Action is missing any aparent way of allowing git push to authenticate successfully. Are you sure this code will be able to push committed changes even after the download is successful?

Comment: @JockX hmm, should be, cuz i have another action works just fine, just not using selenium though. Was wondering if you could write the recommended code to push successfully?

Comment: @KowComical did you find any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue. Please let me know if you found the solution

Comment: @saivinaymanapuram sry for the late response. I did found a solution. The reason i cant find it cause i didnt know the default download path for linux server. However, I know the default download path for windows enviorment is somewhere called 'C://downloads', so, I found a solution that after download, i searched every file in 'C://downloads' for the key word '202204' (the first filename of my file), and got it, and then i output it on the github server